# ZF2: Catching an exception in the dispatch.error event

Tags: php, exception, zend-framework2

My service and model layer often throw `Exception\loginRequired()` and `Exception\incorrectUser()`.  I want to catch these, and if appropriate, redirect the user to a login page, with the original URI and it's parameters appended to the GET string.  Upon successful login, I will then redirect the user to the original request.

I have a function set up in my module class ready to handle dispatch exceptions, but my question is, how do I access the exception?

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    // initialise the event manager
    ...

    // catch exceptions
    $eventManager->attach('dispatch.error', function ($e) {

       // How to access the exception here?

    });
}
```

I need to be able to access the exception to test it's type.

I have checked out the MVC Module, the Event Manager and the Response object, and while I can find references to getError(), they return strings and not exceptions.  How do I get the exception?

I have seen some questions on this topic but they are using the ZfcUser module, which I am not.

Comment: Have a look at how other modules implement their strategies, for example `zfc-rbac` handles `UnauthorizedExceptions` here -> https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac/blob/master/src/ZfcRbac/View/Strategy/UnauthorizedStrategy.php#L59 `bjyauthorize` does it here -> https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/blob/master/src/BjyAuthorize/View/UnauthorizedStrategy.php#L118 and `ZF2` itself does it here -> https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/ExceptionStrategy.php#L123

Comment: Thanks Crisp, just worked that out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after looking at Zend\Mvc\View\Http\ExceptionStrategy I found that the exception is available as a parameter of the MvcEvent, accessible via `$e->getParam('exception');`